# How To avoid Generate Sqlite DB Every time i start the program instead of one time

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

i'v used this code to generate sqlite Database ..

```
 private static SQLiteConnection GenData()
    {
        SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("MyDatabase.sqlite");
        SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection;
        m_dbConnection  new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;");
        m_dbConnection.Open();
        string createTableQuery = @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [MyTable] (
                      [ID] INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                      [Value] VARCHAR(2048)  NULL
                      )";
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(createTableQuery, m_dbConnection);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return m_dbConnection;
    }
```

and i use it in button click to insert Data and Create DB

```
   private void insertintoDB(string Textbox)
    {

        SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection = GenData();
        string sql = "insert into MyTable (Value) values ('" + Textbox + "')";
        SQLiteCommand commmand = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
        commmand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

`insertintoDB(textbox1.text)` 
and i put `GenData()` in load `event`  but every time i use the application .. it auto Generate the database and i need it to be only one time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a simple file check at the location your database is getting created at (typically this is App_Data, though you may want to specify a different location using the appropriate environment variables).

Then create a conditional statement to execute you "CreateFile" command only if the file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Just add an if statement before your Create File

```
private static SQLiteConnection GenData()
{
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists("MyDatabase.sqlite"))
        SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("MyDatabase.sqlite");
    .....
```

This will check whether a file exists before creating it.